# transaction value does not match signed transaction params in ethereumJS-TX

Tags: raw-transaction, ethereumjs-tx

I sign this transaction with Ethereumjs-tx:

```
{ 
    nonce: 8,
    gasPrice: 20,
    gasLimit: 25000,
    to: '0x45cc01d4b9ad49b81527d5b6629da8664bb525d3',
    value: 1000000,
    data: '0x00',
    chainId: 3 
}
```

however, the **value** on etherscan shows 0.013845257383850032 Ether

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xa891e47b6fad75750a40d6ea2698fe409e4650c59acbc910eaa5cabe1169a4e0

Where doe the 0.0038xxxx extra ether come from?

Comment: Are you sure that code produced that transaction? A value of `1000000` is equal to `0.000000000001` ETH (the value you posted is in WEI). I do not think that the code you posted matches the transaction that you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Larger ints don't work well with ethereumJS-tx. If you have a large int, use

**ethereumjs-util.intToBuffer()**

or

new BN(value) to convert it to BN which seems to work as well.